# Room lists not appearing after adding them to the 365 admin portal

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, office365

I've created 3 room lists in 365 admin portal for our 3 meeting rooms.

When opening Outlook and creating a meeting and selecting the room list. The one I've created does not appear? All I can see is this. I also cannot find where I would create a building?

Can anyone please assist?

[image: Screenshot.]

Comment: It has been a while and I am writing to see how things are going on with this issue. Have you had a chance to check the replies provided? Any update would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the room lists may take around 24 hours to start appearing properly in Outlook.

And are you using cache mode? If so, this change may not be valid immediately.

It's suggested that you could change to online mode to check if there're any differences.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.